# convert the following sql query in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Original sql query which is working fine..

```
SELECT image_path FROM `design_details` WHERE UPPER(image_path) LIKE UPPER('%01.jpg%')
```

STORED PROCEDURE FOR THE CORRESPONDING QUERY;

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `checkImageNameExists` (IN `in_image_path` VARCHAR(1000))  
BEGIN

SELECT image_path FROM `design_details` WHERE UPPER(image_path) LIKE UPPER('%'+in_image_path+'%');

END$$
```

I am able to create stored procedure successfully.
When i call stored procedure as

```
CALL checkImageNameExists('01.jpg'); through phpmyadmin
```

IT GIVES ERROR AS FOLLOWS ::
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

> Unrecognized keyword. (near "ON" at position 25)
>   SQL query: Edit Edit

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

I am unable to understand error.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this in your stored procedure

```
SELECT image_path FROM `design_details` WHERE UPPER(image_path) LIKE UPPER('%'+in_image_path+'%');
```

to

```
SELECT image_path FROM `design_details` WHERE UPPER(image_path) LIKE CONCAT('%', UPPER(in_image_path) , '%');
```